# dbscan indices are out-of-bounds python

Tags: python, dbscan

this is my code.

```
from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN

dbscan = DBSCAN(random_state=111)

dbscan.fit(data3)
```

data3 is a pandas dataframe:

```
      FAC1_2    FAC2_2
0   -0.227252 -0.685482
1    0.015251 -0.988252
2   -0.291176 -0.696146
3   -0.747702 -0.708030
4   -0.648103 -0.701741
5   -0.546777 -0.906151
6   -0.141553 -0.689223
7    0.159203 -0.734537
8    0.345847 -0.900163
9   -0.049349 -0.700356
10   0.079924 -0.651371
```

I get the following error:

```
File "/anaconda/anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1632, in _maybe_convert_indices
raise IndexError("indices are out-of-bounds")

IndexError: indices are out-of-bounds
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 9):

the problem was a bug. It doesn't work with pandas dataframe. The solution is to convert the pandas dataframe into a numpy array:

```
data3 = np.array(data3)
```